# Visual Studio Code cannot scan for Type Definition

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, phaser-framework

I am using Visual Studio Code for TypeScript application development. Recently, I'm trying Phaser, and I install Phaser by using Yarn.

```
yarn add phaser-ce
```

I can find the folder phaser-ce in the folder of node_modules and the typescript folder in phaser-ce. However, I found that Visual Studio Code cannot scan the Type Definition. It throw errors when I tried to write a small Phaser application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a definitions.d.ts file within your project to define where type definitions can be found.

For [example](https://github.com/JamesSkemp/phaser-starter-templates/blob/master/v2-ce/_starter-v2-ce-vsc-ts-node/src/ts/definitions.d.ts):

```
/// <reference path='../../node_modules/phaser-ce/typescript/phaser.comments.d.ts' />
```

The path will depend upon your directory structure, but Visual Studio Code is smart enough to tell you if the path is invalid.